# Combine Enum.filter with Enum.each

Tags: elixir

With the following list of maps:

```
[%{test: %{"one" => 1, "three" => 3, "two" => 2}}, ...]
```

Shouldnt this code not filter anything at all?

```
Enum.filter([map], fn(number) ->    
  Enum.each(number.test, fn {k, v} -> 
    v == 4                             
  end)                               
end)
```

How can I make Enum.filter work with a property which is a map itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enum.each` returns `:ok` so your code will always return the same value as input.

If you want to check that *any* value in the map has value 4, you can use `Enum.any?/2`:

```
Enum.any?(number.test, fn {k, v} -> 
  v == 4                             
end)
```

To check if *all* of them have value 4, you can use `Enum.all?/2`:

```
Enum.all?(number.test, fn {k, v} -> 
  v == 4                             
end)
```